# How to match regex for code between curly brackets

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

I need to match all the block which contains this line

```
  role = "${module.iam_basic.ec2_base_instance_role}"
```

My file looks like this

```
module "iam_basic" {
 source = "../../../../modules/aws/iam/ec2"
 base_profile = "staging_srv_profile"
 base_role = "staging_srv_role"
}
resource "aws_iam_role_policy" "s3_bucket_policy" {
name = "s3-policy"
role = "${module.iam_basic.ec2_base_instance_role}"
policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement":[
 {
   "Effect":"Allow",
   "Action":"s3:*",
   "Resource":["arn:aws:s3:::stg-access/*",
              "arn:aws:s3:::stg-access"]

  }
 ]
}
EOF
}
```

So regex should match

```
resource "aws_iam_role_policy" "s3_bucket_policy" {
name = "s3-policy"
role = "${module.iam_basic.ec2_base_instance_role}"
policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement":[
 {
   "Effect":"Allow",
   "Action":"s3:*",
   "Resource":["arn:aws:s3:::stg-access/*",
              "arn:aws:s3:::stg-access"]

  }
 ]
}
EOF
}
```

I was trying to create regex, I came up with this:

```
/^(.*?){([^}]*)}/gm
```

but its not matching properly, Please help me out, if you have any other approach like using tools like grep,awk,sed etc

Comment: Please do add your attempted code in your question, which is highly encouraged on SO, thank you.

Comment: Could you please clarify on: you want to match `role = "${module.iam_basic.ec2_base_instance_role}"` and start printing all lines after that matched line? Does this line `role = "${module.iam_basic.ec2_base_instance_role}"` will always be same format, if not then what else format it could be? Kindly do elaborate more on these points, thank you.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Hi, I want to match the entire block which contains that line, and yes that line will always be in same format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your shown samples only, could you please try following, written and tested in GNU `awk`.

```
awk '
/^module "/{
  if(found){ print val }
  found=""
}
/\<role = "\${module\.iam_basic\.ec2_base_instance_role}"/{
  found=1
}
{
  val=(val?val ORS:"")$0
}
END{
  if(found){ print val }
}' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                        ##Starting awk program from here.
/^module "/{                 ##Checking condition if line starts from module " then do following.
  if(found){ print val }     ##Checking condition if found is SET then print the val.
  found=""                   ##Nullify found here.
}
/^role = "\${module\.iam_basic\.ec2_base_instance_role}"/{ ##Check if line has mentioned pattern in it shown by OP.
  found=1                    ##Set found to 1 here.
}
{
  val=(val?val ORS:"")$0     ##Creating val and keep appending current line values to it.
}
END{                         ##Starting END block of this program from here.
  if(found){ print val }     ##Checking condition if found is SET then print the val.
}' Input_file                ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: Hi, I tried it, but unfortunately, It did not worked for me, here is output https://del.dog/resultregex.txt

Comment: @Ayushwalia, for your given samples it worked fine for me, is your actual data same like shown samples?

Comment: Here is one of the file https://del.dog/regexfile.txt, need to match 2nd, 3rd and 4th block as they have that role line in them

Comment: @Ayushwalia, oh ok got it, I have fixed the regex now, by adding word boundaries in it, code is now working with your shown samples, kindly check it once and let me know then.